# Update objects LinqToSql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have 3 classes:
`BasePlace, Hall, HallPlan`.

Relations:
`BasePlace - Hall`: one-to-many.
`Hall` - `HallPlan`: one-to-many.

I get places(venues) from remote program. I have the following method to add(or update) object:

```
public void AddPremieraPlace(IEnumerable<BasePlace> places)
        {
            if(places != null)
            {
                foreach (var place in places)
                {
                    //is exist in db
                    var dbPlace = Database.BasePlaces.FirstOrDefault(p => p.OIDPremiera == place.OIDPremiera);
                    // if exist update properties and collections
                    if (dbPlace != null)
                    {
                        dbPlace.Name = place.Name
                        dbPlace.Halls = place.Halls;
                    }
                    else
                        Add(place); // just add new place

                    Database.SubmitChanges();                    
                } 

            }
        }
```

When place is exist in the DB then updates works not properly. In the `Hall` and `HallPlan` creates duplicate:
`Hall` table, for example:

```
OID   Name       PlaceId  OIDPremiera
19  Redisson        NULL        1
20  Test 2          NULL        3
21  Test 3          NULL        2

22  Redisson        5           1
23  Test 2          5           3
24  Test 3          5           2
```

How to update correctly?
Thanks.

`Add()`:

```
public virtual void Add(TClass entity)
        {
            Check.Argument.IsNotNull(entity, "entity");

            Database.GetTable<TClass>().InsertOnSubmit(entity);
        }
```

Comment: Is the `PlaceId` column a foreign key to the `BasePlace` table? Are the duplicate lines the ones with `OID` between `22` and `24`?

Comment: What does your add() do.

Comment: @EnricoCampidoglio: Yes, it's FK. Yes, duplicate between 22-24.

Comment: @Pleun: I updated qiestion. Add method not call in this case.

Comment: Where has `place.Halls` come from in this example? did that come from **the same** data-context?

Comment: @MarcGravell: I get xml file from tcp request. Then I parse this xml and create `IEnumarable<BasePlace>` in runtime. Then I passing this collection to the `AddPremieraPlace` method.

Comment: @user348173 so is that a "no" then?

Comment: @MarcGravell: Then "no".

Comment: @MarcGravell: Do you know how to rewrite this code properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ-to-SQL has an identity manager; if it finds something in the tree that it *doesn't recognise* (i.e. isn't in the identity manager), then it assumes it is to be treated as an insert for that item. So because it doesn't recognise your `Hall` instances, it is inserting them.

There are 2 ways to address this:

- rather than directly assigning the `Halls` from your non-L2S model to the L2S model, you could ask the data-context for the **matching** instance, i.e. in a loop, use `ctx.Halls.FirstOrDefault(...)` to get the equivalent `Hall` from the data-context, and add **that** instead of the original
- use the `Attach` method  (i.e. `ctx.Halls.Attach(...)`) to make L2S aware of the hall instances before you start

Comment: I add the following: `Database.BasePlaces.Attach(place);`. No errors, but in the DB no changes.

Comment: @user348173 it isn't the *place* you want to attach; it is the *hall*, no?

Comment: I want `Place` and all collection: `Place.Halls`. The `Hall` have collection `HallPlans`.

Comment: @user348173 yes, but each hall is an object... and it sounds like you want to use the **existing** object from the data-context...?

Comment: Yes, and changes him properties.

Comment: @user348173 then you could [attach-as-dirty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548778.aspx), or: you will need to fetch the **data-context** version of each hall, and re-apply the changes.